# How to transfer it into a `20000` by `1` matrix with float value?

Tags: python

If I have a `20000` by 1 list of 0 and 1 defined by `y_pred`. How to transfer it into a `20000` by `1` matrix with float value?

```
y_pred= list(map(int, y_pred))
```

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0...]
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to start using `numpy` library, it makes data manipulation so easy. Such operation would be as simple as `y_pred.astype(np.float)`.

Comment: If you don't want to, then `y_pred = list(map(float, y_pred))` should do too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you are converting them to int:

```
y_pred = list(map(int, y_pred))
```

so that leads me to think maybe the values of `y_pred` are floats originally? maybe you don't even need to do anything.

If they are not floats originally, you can simply convert them to float instead of int:

```
y_pred = list(map(float, y_pred))
```

Comment: Are `y_pred` a matrix now?

Comment: What do you mean? By default there is no "matrix" type in python as far as I know. This will return a list. If you are talking about a numpy ndarray, you should point it out in your question.